# Creating multiple aggregations using RestHeart

Tags: mongodb, restheart

I am using RestHeart to make REST calls for MOngoDB aggregation queries.I am trying to create multiple aggregations as a one time activity and then execute them whenever i need them later.
Currently I see that only one aggregation gets created at a time. If I create a new one then it gets overwritten.

Is it possible to create multiple aggregations as a one time activity with diferent URI?

This way, I can call URI later and don't have to rewrite the aggregation queries everytime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESTHeart allows to define aggregations via the *aggrs* collection property. See the documentation here https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/AwDw

*aggrs* is an array of aggregation definitions, something like:

```
aggrs: [ { <aggregation_1> }, { <aggregation_2> }, ... ]
```

an aggregation definition is:

```
{
   "type":"pipeline",
   "uri": <uri>,
       "stages": [
       "<stage_1>",
       "<stage_2>",
       ...
   ]
}
```

each aggregation is bound to the uri specified in the definition, under the `/db/coll/_aggrs`, so:

```
GET /db/coll/_aggrs/aggreation1
GET /db/coll/_aggrs/aggreation2
```

You say that your aggregation gets overwritten, I suspect that you are updating your collection replacing the *aggrs* array. Make sure to update the collection properties with all your aggregation definitions in the *aggrs* array

So to create a first aggregation using the brilliant [httpie](https://httpie.org/) cli tool

```
http PATCH <ip>/db/coll aggrs:='[ {<aggregation_1>} ]'
```

To create a second aggregation you can either pass whole the *aggrs* array:

```
 http PATCH <ip>/db/coll aggrs:='[ {<aggregation_1>}, {<aggregation_2>} ]'
```

or add the second one to the *aggrs* array using the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) update operator

```
 http PATCH <ip>/db/coll aggrs:='{"$addToSet": {"aggrs": {<aggregation_2>}}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, I also found it by closely looking at API spec. If I need to append or update the aggregation which is already present in _proprties, what should I do.

Comment: I mean. Do I need to add another aggr in original JSON and run PUT REST call? or should I run a different REST call with different JSON

Comment: I used postman to send PATCH  calls. But for some reason it's not working. Not sure what could be wrong.

Comment: Note that the documentation for aggregations has moved here: https://restheart.org/docs/mongodb-rest/aggregations